# What does ""To rule this wreath"" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

I was listening to this song: **Secret Ceremony by Millennium Parade**.

At the end of the song, the lyrics is like this:

***Let me tell what do to***

***Just love me now***

***Cause we are gonna be the king and queen***

***To rule this wreath***

Now Cambridge and Lexico(Oxford) dictionaries are saying **Wreath** means

Either: *a ring made of flowers and leaves or evergreens.*

Or: *Snow drift*

These two meanings don't make sense to me and feels like don't match with the context.

Can anyone please help to decode this lyrics especially the last line?

Song link: https://youtu.be/vpcpip5au-0

Dictionary: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wreath

[image: Netflix Sshot Wreath]

Comment: There are apparently different versions of this song and those lines do not appear in any of its lyrics that I can find. The word 'wreath' in the video isn't all that clear (I can only hear 'ree'), and the subtitles might have guessed what they are singing. But anyway, in a song or in poetry, there doesn't *have* to be a meaning.

Comment: It's "Let me tell **you** what to do."  In any case, wreath makes no sense here at all. Could be poor understanding of English by Japanese producers.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have added a screen shot from Netflix where it is literally singing the word **Wreath**. Now do you think that word was generated by the AI?

Comment: This song is from Japan and they obviously had no English reviewers. The word wreath here does not make sense in English.

Comment: @Ghost yes that's my point. I read the subtitles and said that the writer may have misheard a word that isn't very clear. If I close my eyes to the titles and just listen, I cannot hear the word 'wreath' in your link. Even on UK television some speech from a native speaker reported by a UK media titling company is sometimes incorrect.

Comment: @Lambie Now that makes sense. I am not a fan of Japanese stuff. This one was a random song from a techno playlist. I have to say the music and the melody are great. 
However, the lyrics put me into a surreal world where I was keep doubting my English. 

I think they wanted to say **Earth**. Because a lot of Asians cannot pronounce that one properly.

Comment: @Lambie: Or *Let me **say** what do to*. Nns often find the subtly different syntactic affordances of ***tell*** and ***say / explain / describe / ...*** confusing.

Comment: ***Wreathe*** is closely associated with ***ring***. So perhaps the reference alludes to Tolkein's LOTR - ***one ring to bind them, and rule them all***. Allusions like that can still work even if they're generated by non-Anglophones who don't *quite* understand the "standard" syntax / vocabulary for a context.

Answer (score 3):

Song lyrics are like poetry, and as such their meaning can be rather subjective. Looking at the context can sometimes help make sense of songs, however you shouldn't expect song lyrics to make literal sense. Many in fact are arguably nonsense.

It might be better to see if you can find if the song lyrics are published officially.  Youtube subtitles often contain mistakes, especially if the enunciation of the words isn't clear. Like user @wethervane commented above, I can't actually hear the word "wreath". It just sounds like "re" to me. Could it even be "dream"? I'm just not sure.

Anyway, assuming the lyrics are correct, the literal meaning of wreath is not the only one. In English we can use words figuratively. There's also some cultural context you may be unaware of.  Wreaths (of flowers) are commonly placed on graves, during funerals.  The next line of this verse continues with "of pleasure and death". Note: I can't actually hear the word "death" either, so take this with a pinch of salt.

Make of that what you will!!

Comment: WoW, I think I have figured it out .

If it is **To rule this wreath of pleasure and death.** Then it makes sense buddy. Brides wear Wreaths of flowers which symbolize a New beginning, Happiness and Joy. Wreath of flowers symbolizes Death, Sad and totally opposite of Pleasure. They want to choose which Wreath a person is going to receive.


 

If we gather all those pieces together then it should sound like this:
**We are going to be the king and queen and together we will control everyone's fate with our power.** As if like a god.

Comment: @Ghost Yes, they can. Wreaths are also often hung on doors during Christmas and New Year.  But in western countries at least, brides don't wear wreaths. They carry a bouquet of flowers, which isn't the same thing as a wreath.  Words can have multiple meanings and associations, though. And different people will see and associate them with different things.